# PHP array construction from another array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi frnds as I am new to PHP, I was stuck somewhere in array modification. The problem is that I am getting an array from one of my query to database. Now I am in a situation where I have to form an array of arrays of same type with it's count. I don't know what id or name I will get but I have to convert them into an array of common names and Id with it's number of count in the array which I get.

Array which I get from query -

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [type_id] => 1 [name] => VVIP ) [1] => Array ( [type_id] => 1 [name] => VVIP ) [2] => Array ( [type_id] => 2 [name] => Normal ) [3] => Array ( [type_id] => 2 [name] => Normal ) )
```

Convert Into array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [type_id] => 1 [name] => VIP [count] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [type_id] => 2 [name] => Normal [count] => 2 ) )
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What do you need help with?

Comment: I need array of arrays with same name and Id and count field in that array which shows the number of times we have this sub array on the array which I get.

Answer (score 1):

You say this array comes from a database, maybe you can count in the database ?

```
SELECT type_id, name, count(*) FROM yourTable GROUP BY type_id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the counting in your `SQL` code and it will automatically be part of the array, no conversion will be needed.

`COUNT()` is your friend [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $dex = $value['type_id'];
    if (isset($out[$dex])){
        $out[$dex]['count']++;
    } else {
        $out[$dex] = $value;
        $out[$dex]['count'] = 1;
    }
}
$out = array_values($out); 
dump_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => 1
            [name] => VVIP
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => 2
            [name] => Normal
            [count] => 2
        )

)
```